# Reusing soil with earthworms in pots?

Tags: plant-health, soil, potting-soil, worms, earthworms

I have several potted plants, and just today I noticed I have an infestation of small earthworms.

I’ll be washing and repotting all these plants with fresh soil, but I don’t know what to do with the soil I have now.

Can soil with earthworms be reused in pots, even if it’s with decorative plants? Is it possible to “clean” the soil for reuse?

Or should I just throw it away?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Earthworms are beneficial to soil . I have never deliberately added them to a pot , but I know some soil I have used contain them . If you know a gardener , they would likely love to have your "bad" soil.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked similar questions before, and the answer is the same: wildlife doesn't belong in plant pots.

You could go through all the soil and pick out the worms (and turn them loose in your garden or somebody else's, rather than killing them) but who knows what else is in there, if you are using unsterilized soil or compost.

If you put a cost on your own time, all this washing and repotting is probably as expensive as buying the right compost at the start - not to mention the stress you are putting on the plants.